# rbenv on wsl shows ruby version 2.5.0-dev

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, rbenv

I installed `rbenv` on ***WSL*** but it only shows that I have **ruby** `2.5.0-dev`. I checked [ruby's website](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) and it showed 3.1.2. I then checked [rbenv on github](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) and it showed that the updated `rbenv` is `3.1.2`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Note that the version of rbenv that is packaged and maintained in the Debian and Ubuntu repositories is out of date. To install the latest version, it is recommended to install rbenv using git.

Use this to install the latest version: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-git-checkout

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).